# Group of order $3k$ has subgroup of index $3$ - simple proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $3k$ with $gcd(k,6) = 1$ (so $2 \nmid k, 3 \nmid k$). Why does $G$ always have a subgroup of index $3$?

If there is a subgroup of index $3$ then it will be normal - this question is about the existence of such a subgroup though.

The result actually follows from Feit-Thompson and existence of Hall subgroups but this is too overpowered. I'm looking for an simple proof, something like:

If $G$ is a counterexample with $|G|$ minimal and $H$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup with $3 \nmid |H|$, then $G/H$ has a subgroup of index $3$, and its preimage in $G$ would then be index $3$ in $G$. So WLOG every nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ has order divisible by $3$. How can one finish the argument?

Comment: This follows by the Burnside normal $p$-complement theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_p-complement#Burnside_normal_p-complement_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|G|=3k$, with gcd$(6,k)=1$, this implies not only that $3$ is the *smallest* prime dividing the order of $G$, but also that $3$ is the *highest* power of $3$, dividing the order. Hence, a Sylow $3$-subgroup $P$ is cyclic. A well-know theorem (non-trivial, based on transfer theory, see for example M.I. Isaacs, *[Finite Group Theory](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, (5.14) Corollary) implies that $G$ has a normal $3$-complement, that is, there exists an $N$ normal in $G$, such that $G=PN$ and $P \cap N=1$. Hence $|G:N|=3$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks! I guess these normal p-complement theorems is about the easiest approach possible

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about another approach but without any luck.